# Countries where ICOs can be conducted

Tags: ico-initial-coin-offering

I'm trying to find the way to understand where ICOs have been conducted.

Though there are many articles written on how favourable a country is to the practice of ICO (eg. http://fintechnews.sg/12836/blockchain/the-state-of-icos-around-the-world/), I haven't yet found sufficient information on ***where*** exactly ICOs have been launched.

My understanding is that, since ICOs are conducted on the Internet, it is the geological location where the project team is located that is important in terms of regulation.

For example, I understand that Ethereum was launched "in Switzerland" since its team ([Ethereum Foundation](https://www.ethereum.org/foundation)) is apparently "located" in Switzerland.

However, there are other projects whose "birthplace" is not clear.

For example, [IOTA](https://iota.org/) has [seven main developers](https://github.com/iotaledger) in total but their geological locations aren't limited to one particular country (Germany, the US, New Zealand etc).

I'd appreciate it if someone could provide some insight into how to recognise ***where*** an ICO is launched.

Thank you.

Comment: Why is the location important?

Comment: @Max Vernon
When talking about ICO ecosystems around the world, people often talk about the subject in terms of countries (or their locations) in which ICOs are conducted. In addition, different countries (locations) have different regulatory frameworks which will then affect the way in which ICOs are operated.

Comment: The OP is asking where they won’t be jailed for running an unregistered security and selling it to consumers. More of a question for a lawyer really.

Comment: @eponymous I think what I'm asking is how to determine the "location" or "country" of an ICO project, especially when the team members are distributed around the world as is the case in IOTA.

Comment: Setup a registered office somewhere comfortable for an ICO and everybody telecommutes.